# How to print variables data in controller's PHP file

Tags: magento2.4.3

Here is my index.php file code
**Path : /var/www/html/m243/app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
 public function execute()
    {
       
        $url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
            'wpsharecart/index/viewcart', ['id' => $this->urlEncoder->encode($this->session->getQuoteId())]
        );
        $siteurl = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl();


        /*Bitly URL Convert Code START*/
        
            $long_url = $url;
            $apiv4 = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten';
            $genericAccessToken = 'xyzxyyzabcabcbcbcbcbcbcbccccc';

            $data = array(
                'long_url' => $long_url
             );
            $payload = json_encode($data);

            $header = array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $genericAccessToken,
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)
            );

            $ch = curl_init($apiv4);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $resultToJson = json_decode($result);
            //echo $resultJson->link;           

        /*Bitly URL Convert Code END*/

        $resultToJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultToJson->setData($url);
        return $resultToJson;
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        //return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
```

> I want to print  **$resultToJson = json_decode($result);** data,

I tried many codes but it's not working
like

> **echo $resultToJson**

> **print_r($resultToJson)**

no, any solution worked for me.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are overriding the $resultToJson which contains your data..

try renaming this:
`$resultToJson = json_decode($result);`
in
`$data = json_decode($result);`

then:

```
$resultToJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
$resultToJson->setData($data);
return $resultToJson;
```

More info here: https://meetanshi.com/blog/return-json-response-from-controller-in-magento-2/